# how to find the radix complemnt for integer in java?

Tags: java

I need a function that could find the radix complement for any given integer

```
public static int findRadixComplement(int num) {
    // write your code here
    int count = 0, a = 10;
    int numy = num;
    while (numy != 0) {
        numy /= 10;
        ++count;
    }
    int rad = (int) Math.pow(a, count) - num;
    return rad;
}
```

I assume the problem is when I try to input "10", it will output "90"
I also try to use for loop instead of math.pow, it didn't work
there isn't much time left before the deadline

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead [edit] your question to include the code and error messages as text. Does the site tell you which example has failed? Can the list of examples on the left be scrolled?

Comment: Radix complement: b^{n}- y , or in your code a^{count}-num .  Which produces 90 for num=10 which is correct.  What is your expected result and actual ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

To get radix complement, you need to add 1 to `rad`.